# Are "Does feature x in software y exist?" good questions?

Tags: discussion, question-quality

I am searching for a feature of catkin. I looked at the catkin -h page and at the online documentation and tried to google but could not find it. Now I am not sure if asking does this feature exist is a good question. I feel like sometimes there are some really useful small things that developers know, but that are not too obvious at first, for example [this question.](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/541/best-way-to-search-my-shells-history) But sometimes the answer might also be no it doesn't. What is a sensible thing to do?

Comment: Sounds too much like offloading product research onto SO users.  No thanks.

Comment: What is "catkin"?

Comment: Didn't we kill off Documentation? ;-)

Answer (score 21, accepted):

No, it's not a good question.

If you want to know how to do X, then *ask how to do X*.  If you get an answer that is, "feature Y does X" then so be it.  If you get an answer saying, "use this function I just wrote to do X" or "you can use this third party library to do X", then you have those answers as well.  You can accept whichever of those you think is the best, and the community can upvote whichever answers *they* think is best, whether that's using a language feature, custom code, or whatever else.

Of course, if you're going to ask, "how do I do X?" you need to make sure that it's a reasonably scoped problem, else your question will be closed as too broad, and be sure to do your research.  If you can easily find lots of solutions for how to do X when looking around then that's not an appropriate question (unless you can explain how all of the solutions you've found don't work or have a problem that is unacceptable for you, in which case you'd need to explain what you found, and what the problems with those solutions were).

And of course doing X would need to be a programming problem, else the question would be off topic.

Comment: What's a valid close reason for such questions (the kind in the OP)? I usually struggle to find a good close reason

Comment: @Justin There is no close reason that's going to apply to all such questions.  Any or none of the close reasons might apply to any particular such question.

Answer (score 1):

If the feature is not documented anywhere, and you haven't seen anything like it in the wild, chances are it doesn't exist. Such a question may get downvoted even if you state that you've looked in the man page and online docs, because it can come across as skeptical, and if such a feature truly doesn't exist, then answers will just amount to "No, it doesn't exist." which incidentally doesn't even meet the 30-character requirement for answers.<sup>1</sup>

If there's evidence that an undocumented feature is being used in the wild, and you want to know how this feature works, that's something that's worth asking IMO, but only because seeing it in the wild is a presumption that it *does* in fact exist in *some* form. The ideal answer would explain how it works to the best of the answerer's ability, while reiterating its undocumented nature and cautioning readers against using it in production.

Either way, the question of *whether* something exists will usually be answered by your research and the conclusions you make based on your research long before you even ask it.

Having said that, I'd still keep Servy's guidance in mind. There's a chance said feature you're thinking of asking about is an X solution to a Y problem, and if you're actually interested in solving the Y problem rather than the hypothetical feature X, make your question *about that Y problem* so you can receive more suitable answers.

---

<sup>1</sup> <sub>Usually, I make up for this with some exposition speculating *why* such a feature doesn't exist, or pointing to sources indicating that said feature may appear in future versions or standards, but I'm not a fan of answering such questions to begin with and the reason should be clear why.</sub>

Answer (score -3):

I'd argue that it's a poor question for Stack Overflow, since we don't fundamentally field questions about *Software Y*.

Comment: Although we generally answer questions that are about software tools commonly used by programmers. But I agree that it would be a poor question.

Answer (score -3):

I'd say that in some cases it's a perfectly good question. For example if you've thoroughly searched the documentation for some Java library and the documentation doesn't tell you whether a particular class is thread-safe, it's entirely reasonable to ask here.

Comment: Yes ... but thread-safety is a property, not a feature.  (And I'm not just splitting hairs.)  A feature ("supports XYZ") is far more likely to be mentioned in the documentation than a property.  So if some feature is not mentioned it is unlikely to exist.  (And your example is an edge-case; i.e. thread-safety is a property that is frequently not properly documented properly!)

Comment: _"the documentation doesn't tell you whether a particular class is thread-safe"_ -- not thread-safe is the default. Even if we allow "thread-safe" as equivalent to the "feature x" being asked about in the question here, if the documentation does not indicate an object, method, etc. is thread-safe, then you can only assume it isn't. Even if it just accidentally was thread-safe today, without a promise in the documentation of that, it could change in the future, breaking your code. Asking if a feature exists is never a good question; it demonstrates zero research.

Comment: Well I'll take another example then. The SAX interface for XML parsers has a method setFeature(uri), and the interface documentation says every implementation must support the feature with uri=X. You instantiate a parser that claims to implement this interface, and you get an error that suggests it doesn't recognize the feature with uri=X. The documentation doesn't help you. I think it's then perfectly reasonable to ask here whether parser P supports feature X.

Comment: And here's another example: "does Xalan support tail-call optimization"? Details of what optimizations particular processors support can be very hard to ascertain, and the fact that you don't know certainly doesn't indicate lack of research (unless you expect people to study the source code...). And it can be important to the viability of an application that you know the answer. (And don't tell me that tail call optimization isn't a feature, or at the very least find a definition of "feature" the supports your thesis.)

Comment: I think the question asks about something different. All of your examples are about more or less technical properties/capabilities. As I interpret the questions it is more about questions along the line of "Is there a flag for grep that allows to do magic?"

Comment: @MichaelKay If a product is documented as having a feature, and  you go to use it, and it doesn't work, then you don't have a question about whether a given product has a given feature.  You already know the answer to that.  You have a question about how you're using a feature incorrectly to result in an error (or the far less likely possibility of a bug in that product).  Either way, you have a question about a problem you're having, not about the existence of a feature.

Comment: @MichaelKay Whether a language supports tail call optimization is very likely to be easily found with research.  Most commonly used languages are going to have readily available information on whether or not it's supported, and even if it's not, it's quite trivial to write a method that should use the optimization and then simply see if the stack fills up or not; it's a solution where the answer is trivially found.

Comment: @Servy No, you don't know the answer (and if you think you do, then you have jumped to a premature conclusion). There are many possible explanations. The feature might not be present in some versions of the product, it might need to be enabled through some configuration option, the documentation might be completely wrong, your use of the product might be completely wrong, you might not be using the product you think you are using etc etc. Of course your real question is "why isn't X working?" but asking "is X supported?" is a perfectly reasonable way of phrasing that.

Comment: @MichaelKay If you have documentation saying that a feature is supported, then yes, you *do* know, by definition, that it's supported.  You could be using the product incorrectly, or it could have a bug, but regardless of the reason for that problem, the only actual question you have is why you're having the problem that you're having using the feature.  If you ask if it exists, all you'll get is an answer telling you what you already know, that yes, it's documented as being a feature.  Asking the question that you already know the answer to *isn't* a reasonable way of asking that question.

Comment: @Servy You have more trust in documentation than I do. And I write the stuff.